# Underline active link slideToggle (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle, underline

I made a text page where information pops up when the user clicks on a link using `slideToggle()`.

When you click on the next link, the previous text passage automatically closes (also using `slideToggle`).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.textbox a').next('.textbox p').hide();
    jQuery('.textbox a').click(function() {
        $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.textbox p').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.textbox {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.textbox a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox1" class="textbox">
    <a>Link1</a>
    <p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
<div id="textbox2" class="textbox">
    <a>Link2</a>
    <p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
<div id="textbox3" class="textbox">
    <a>Link3</a>
    <p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
<div id="textbox4" class="textbox">
    <a>Link4</a>
    <p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
```

How can I get the active "link" underlined? I have tried several things but the closest I could get was that every link was underlined once a single one was active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS `text-decoration:underline;`.

Whatever you do in CSS, as long as you apply it to the `.active` class, it will be applied only to the active link.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".textbox a").next(".textbox p").hide();
    jQuery(".textbox a").click(function() {
        $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.textbox p').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.textbox{           width: 50px;
                    text-align: center;
                    float: left;}

.textbox a{         cursor: pointer;}
/* This is the only line you need to add: */
/* Or you could use border-bottom:1px solid black; instead. */
.active {text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textbox1" class="textbox">
    <a>Link1</a><p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
<div id="textbox2" class="textbox">
    <a>Link2</a><p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
<div id="textboxe" class="textbox">
    <a>Link3</a><p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
<div id="textbox4" class="textbox">
    <a>Link4</a><p>Text that is toggled.</p>
</div>
```